# Using sed to modify line not containing string

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script that uses sed to modify lines in a config file not containing a specific string.  To illustrate by example, I could have ...

```
/some/file/path1 ipAddress1/subnetMask(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
/some/file/path2 ipAddress1/subnetMask(rw,sync,no_root_squash,anonuid=-1)
/some/file/path3 ipAddress2/subnetMask(rw,sync,no_root_squash,anonuid=0)
/some/file/path4 ipAddress2/subnetMask(rw,sync,no_root_squash,anongid=-1)
/some/file/path5 ipAddress2/subnetMask(rw,sync,no_root_squash,anonuid=-1,anongid=-1)
```

And I want every line's parenthetical list to be changed such that it contains strings `anonuid=-1` and `anongid=-1` within its parentheses ...

```
/some/file/path1 ipAddress1/subnetMask(rw,sync,no_root_squash,anonuid=-1,anongid=-1)
/some/file/path2 ipAddress1/subnetMask(rw,sync,no_root_squash,anonuid=-1,anongid=-1)
/some/file/path3 ipAddress2/subnetMask(rw,sync,no_root_squash,anonuid=-1,anongid=-1)
/some/file/path4 ipAddress2/subnetMask(rw,sync,no_root_squash,anongid=-1,anonuid=-1)
/some/file/path5 ipAddress2/subnetMask(rw,sync,no_root_squash,anonuid=-1,anongid=-1)
```

As can be seen from the example, both `anonuid` and `anongid` may already exist within the parentheses, but it is possible that the original parenthetical list has one string but not the other (lines 2, 3, and 4), the list has neither (line 1), the list has both already set properly (line 5), or even one or both of them are set incorrectly (line 3). When either `anonuid` or `anongid` is set to a value other than `-1`, it must be changed to the proper value of `-1` (line 3).

What would be the best way to edit my config file using sed such that `anonuid=-1` and `anongid=-1` is contained in each line's parenthetical list, separated by a comma delimiter of course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
sed -e '/anonuid/{s/anonuid=[-0-9]*/anonuid=-1/;b gid;};s/)$/,anonuid=-1)/;:gid;/anongid/{s/anongid=[-0-9]*/anongid=-1/;b;};s/)$/,anongid=-1)/'
```

Basically, it has two nearly identical parts with the first dealing with anonuid and the second anongid, each with a bit of logic to decide if it needs to replace or add the appropriate values. (It doesn't bother to check if the value is already correct, that would just complicate things while not changing the results.)

Comment: Thanks William!  It looks like this almost does the trick.  The only thing you forgot is the close parentheses in the end.  Could you please edit your answer to have that functionality?  Thank you!

Comment: It still will not put in parentheses for something like line 1 ... `echo "/home/cdg/jas_inbound_backup 192.168.5.175/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_root_squash)" | sed '/anonuid/{s/anonuid=[-0-9]*/anonuid=-1/;b gid;};s/)$/,anonuid=-1)/;:gid;/anongid/{s/anongid=[-0-9]*/anongid=-1)/;b;};s/)$/,anongid=-1/'` results in no close parentheses.

Comment: Also, one or both strings already being in these results in multiple end parentheses ... `echo "/some/file/path1 ipAddress1/subnetMask(rw,sync,no_root_squash,anongid=0)" | sed '/anonuid/{s/anonuid=[-0-9]*/anonuid=-1/;b gid;};s/)$/,anonuid=-1)/;:gid;/anongid/{s/anongid=[-0-9]*/anongid=-1)/;b;};s/)$/,anongid=-1/'` results in `/some/file/path1 ipAddress1/subnetMask(rw,sync,no_root_squash,anongid=-1),anonuid=-1)`

Comment: Sorry, I realized it was missing that last paren, edited it and accidentally put it in the wrong place. It's fixed and tested now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed to specify the lines you are interested in:

```
$ sed '/anonuid=..*,anongid=..*)$/!p' $file
```

The above will print (`p`) all lines that don't match the regular expression between the two slashes. I ***negated*** the expression by using the `!`. This way, you're not matching lines with both `anaonuid` and `anongid` in them.

Now, you can work on the non-matching lines and editing those with the sed `s` command:

```
$ sed '/anonuid=..*,anongid=..*)$/!s/from/to/`
```

The manipulation might be fairly complex, and you might be passing multiple `sed` commands to get everything *just right*.

However, if the string `no_root_squash` appear in each line you want to change, why not take the simple way out:

```
$ sed 's/no_root_squash.*$/no_root_squash,anonuid=-1,anongid=-1)/' $file
```

This is looking for that `no_root_squash` string, and replacing everything from that string to the end of the line with the text you want. Are there lines you are touching that don't need to be *edited*? Yes, but you're not really changing those lines. You're basically substituting `/no_root_squash,anonuid=-1,anongid=-1)` with the same `/no_root_squash,anonuid=-1,anongid=-1)`.

This may be faster even though it's replacing text that doesn't need replacing because there's less processing going on. Plus, it's easier to understand and support in the future.

#### Response

> Thanks David! Yeah I was considering going that route, but I didn't want to rely 100% on every line containing no_root_squash. My current config file only ends in that string, but I'm just not 100% sure that won't potentially be different in the field. Do you think there would be a way to change that so it just overwrites from the end of the last string not containing anonuid=-1 or anongid=-1 onward?

What can you guarantee will be in each line?

You might be able to do a capture group:

```
 sed 's/\(sync,[^,)]*\).*/\1,anonuid=-1,anongid=-1)/' $file
```

The `\(..\)` is a *capture group*. It basically captures that portion of the matching regular expression, and then allows you to reuse it via the `\1`. I'm capturing from the word `sync` to a group of characters not including a comma or a closing parentheses. Then, I'm appending the capture group, a comma, and your anon uid and gid.

Will that work?

Comment: Thanks David! Yeah I was considering going that route, but I didn't want to rely 100% on every line containing `no_root_squash`. My current config file only ends in that string, but I'm just not 100% sure that won't potentially be different in the field. Do you think there would be a way to change that so it just overwrites from the end of the last string not containing `anonuid=-1` or `anongid=-1` onward?

Comment: @ David W. This also seems like a great, concise solution. But ideally, I don't want to guarantee any particular string pre-exists in the config file. I apologize for not explicitly stating this in my description and showing such a trend in my example. All I can guarantee is that there will be a parenthetical list of something separated by a comma delimiter and that it needs to be modified to contain the two strings I described.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am oversimplifying:

```
sed 's/anonuid=[-0-9]*[^)]//g;s/anongid=[-0-9]*[^)]//g;s/[)]/anonuid=-1,anongid=-1)/g' test.txt > test3.txt
```

This just drops any current instance of `anonuid` or `anongid` and adds the string 
`"anonuid=-1,anongid=-1"` into the parentheses

Comment: This solution seems to work for the most part too scott.  I briefly tested it against a few cases and only found that its missing a comma in the following case.  `echo "/some/file/path1 ipAddress1/subnetMask(rw,sync,no_root_squash)" | sed 's/anonuid=[-0-9]*[^)]//g;s/anongid=[-0-9]*[^)]//g;s/[)]/anonuid=-1,anongid=-1)/g'` results in `/some/file/path1 ipAddress1/subnetMask(rw,sync,no_root_squashanonuid=-1,anongid=-1)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm currently teaching myself bash scripting with the aid of this and other websites, I will try to adjust this to make it work as a learning challenge